# Jquery prevent link but keep url anchor

Tags: jquery, html

I have links that contain href="#video1"

I need to prevent the click executions with

```
$( "#accordion_video a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

but when I do that **I don't get `#video1`** in url like this `http://example.com/#video1` and **I need that** for the going back history. And if **I don't prevent it** the page blank the center part. Any idea?

[Demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/rrap23z2/)

Comment: Are you trying to do something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Comment: the duplicate doesn't work for me! And it's not the same. I need to keep the anchor tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you

```
$( "#accordion_video a" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    history.pushState("", "", window.location.href.split("#")[0] + $(this).attr('href'))
});
```

edited: use window.location.href.split("#")[0] instead of window.location.href

Comment: hm, this works but it does nothing when hitting back button. Probably because tags keep adding one after the other so the broser doesn't know which to go. Like this http://example.com/#video1#video2#video3. But here is the right direction...

Comment: yeah, it works how I wanted but the problem is if I hit the back button I get the blank center. I think it's not going to work for my site since I'm trying to use it for the videos back history. See here http://help.overdrive.com/?t=600693#videos when you click the videos that's where I'm trying to make history to work.

Comment: you can use  window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) { "code here" }).  Inside this function you should load the video the same way the click event loads it. The popstate event fires when you go back in history

Comment: actually something like this may work: window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) { $("a[href=" + location.hash + "]").click() }).

Comment: it gets stuck when going back.